# Synchronize of thread cause deadlock?

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe7

The same project runs perfect on Windows/iOS platform, but cause deadlock on Android (two different android devices) after running for uncertain duration.

```
procedure TTestThread.FSynProc;
begin
  Inc(Form1.FExecuted); //Variable of TForm
  Form1.Text1.Text:= IntToStr(Form1.FExecuted);
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
var
begin
  while not Self.Terminated do
  begin
    Self.Synchronize(FSynProc);
    sleep(10);
  end;
end;

constructor TTestThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  Self.FreeOnTerminate:= True;
end;

destructor TTestThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

code for launch TTestThread

```
procedure TForm1.StartTTProc;
begin
  ftt:= TTestThread.Create; // Variable of TForm
  ftt.Start;
end;
```

After StartTTProc, the number shows in 'Text1' increase continusely.
After running for an uncertain duration on android device, App freezed.
any advice?

Comment: It would be a lot better if you removed the code that you added in your trial and error phase. ProcessMessages and the Sleep

Comment: @TLama  changed to the original code.

Comment: The code seems fine.  Have you tried debugging?  Where is the deadlock?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Not surprising really. Emba don't have a good record in the field of threading. Perhaps you would submit a report to Quality Portal.

Comment: Seems related to this quality portal report; [Animation timer stops responding](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9986?jql=text%20~%20%22android%20thread%22).